# "bound m" show in angular ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, rest, restangular

I use `restangular` to connect to REST API. I define a `ProductService.js` with this code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app').service('ProductService', function($rootScope, Restangular) {
    // Build collection /product URL
    var _productService = Restangular.all('product');

    this.list = function() {
    // GET /api/product
         return _productService.getList();
    }

    this.create = function(product) {
        // POST /api/product/:id
        _productService.post(product).then(function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('product.create');
        });
    }
});
```

and I use this service in `ProductController.js`:

```
"use strict";

app.controller('ProductController',function($scope,$http,Restangular,ProductService){

     // get products
     $scope.products = ProductService.list();

    // create product
    $scope.create = function(product) {
        ProductService.create(product);
    };

    // Event Listeners
    $scope.$on('product.create', function(product) {
        $scope.products = ProductService.list();
        console.log('product create');
    });

});
```

and anythings is okay when page load and after that when create a product show me this page:
[image: page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved problem and add `$object` to list function in `ProductService.js`:

```
    this.list = function() {
        // GET /api/product
        return _productService.getList().$object;
    }
```